# Null pointer exception in java POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

Here's the code

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\xyz.xls"));
 HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
```

and on execution I get following exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.aggregates.ValueRecordsAggregate.construct(ValueRecordsAggregate.java:173)
        at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.Sheet.createSheet(Sheet.java:206)
        at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:216)
        at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:153)
        at com.tcs.sgv.SLB.util.ExportSLBExcel.exportTargetCondForm(ExportSLBExcel.java:18448)
        at com.tcs.sgv.SLB.DAO.SLBIndicatorDAOImpl.getTargetModelData(SLBIndicatorDAOImpl.java:604)
        at com.tcs.sgv.SLB.handler.SLBIndicatorRequestHandler.processAction(SLBIndicatorRequestHandler.java:282)
```

Excel file is in 97-2003 format,please help to resolve it.Thnx in advance.

Comment: I guess the value in excel sheet is empty .If u have empty cells in excel sheet delete some empty items and try it out .

Comment: The above code you mentioned works properly with out any errors.

Comment: The information seems insufficient... as the provided code is working fine...

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using? And if it isn't the latest, have you tried upgrading?

Comment: M using POI 3.5 beta version.

Comment: Yes there are empty cells in my excel sheet.Is there any way this code could work with empty values in sheet?